# Using a boolean from another class

Tags: c#, boolean

So I seem to be having issues accessing a public boolean from one .cs file in another within the same project.

Both are within the same project and namespace, the boolean as below is declared as public yet when I try to check if true in the second file it says it is not defined.

I define the boolean in the code below:

```
public bool CXML_ProjectLoaded()
    {
        if (CXML_CreateProjectFiles_EmptyFieldCheck() == false)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

In my second file I then try to use it as an if true:

```
public void CXML_ProjectLoadVisibility()
    {
        if (CXML_ProjectLoaded() == false)
        {
            // Remove the Tabs.

            // Project Overview
            CXML_MainPage_TabControl_Main.Items.Remove(CXML_TabHeader_ProjOver);
            //Kingdoms
            CXML_MainPage_TabControl_Main.Items.Remove(CXML_TabHeader_Kingdom);
            //Clans
            CXML_MainPage_TabControl_Main.Items.Remove(CXML_TabHeader_Clans);
            //Lords
            CXML_MainPage_TabControl_Main.Items.Remove(CXML_TabHeader_Lords);
            //Cultures
            CXML_MainPage_TabControl_Main.Items.Remove(CXML_TabHeader_Cultures);
            //Settlements
            CXML_MainPage_TabControl_Main.Items.Remove(CXML_TabHeader_Settlements);
            //Items
            CXML_MainPage_TabControl_Main.Items.Remove(CXML_TabHeader_Items);

        }
        else if (CXML_ProjectLoaded() ==true)
        {

            // Add back the tabs

            // Project Overview
            CXML_MainPage_TabControl_Main.Items.Add(CXML_TabHeader_ProjOver);
            //Kingdoms
            CXML_MainPage_TabControl_Main.Items.Add(CXML_TabHeader_Kingdom);
            //Clans
            CXML_MainPage_TabControl_Main.Items.Add(CXML_TabHeader_Clans);
            //Lords
            CXML_MainPage_TabControl_Main.Items.Add(CXML_TabHeader_Lords);
            //Cultures
            CXML_MainPage_TabControl_Main.Items.Add(CXML_TabHeader_Cultures);
            //Settlements
            CXML_MainPage_TabControl_Main.Items.Add(CXML_TabHeader_Settlements);
            //Items
            CXML_MainPage_TabControl_Main.Items.Add(CXML_TabHeader_Items);
        }
        else
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Broken Stuff!");
        }
    }
```

However this is where VS says CXML_ProjectLoaded doesn't exist.

As per the below screenshot they are both in the same project:

[Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5jcVz.png)

Comment: Are the both files belong to same class (like partial)....if not you have to create an object to access the function.

Comment: In the way you try to access method both methods need to belong to same class. Are they?

Comment: Your `CXML_ProjectLoaded()` function can be reduced to: `return !CXML_CreateProjectFiles_EmptyFieldCheck()`.  It may also be a good candidate for being a read-only property

Comment: *"Broken Stuff!"* - The only way this is going to happen is if the result of `CXML_ProjectLoaded()` can change between calls. This looks like a good candiate for a simple if/else...  `if (!CXML_ProjectLoaded()) {/*Remove calls*/} else {/* Add calls*/}` .

Comment: Then you have `if (CXML_ProjectLoaded() == false) { stuff(); } else if (CXML_ProjectLoaded() == true) {otherStuff();} else {moreStuff()}`.  A boolean function will not return something other than `true` or `false`.  In fact, you only need to call it once, and you don't need to compare it to `true` or to `false`; it already is one of those values

Answer (score 0):

Realised I needed to do Window1.Boolean instead :)